# How to load and repeat-x an image with php gd?

Tags: php, gd, repeat, imagecreatefrompng

Suppose i have an image with width 1px and height 40px.
I want to load it with lets say imagecreatefrompng and want to x-repeat it, just like css repeat-x.

Is this possible with PHP GD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify width of output image, I have chosen `1024` to demonstrate:

```
$srcfile = 'bg.jpg';
$outfile = 'background.jpg';
list($src_w,$src_h,$src_type) = getimagesize($srcfile);

$out_w = 1024;
$out_h = $src_h;

$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($srcfile);
$out = imagecreatetruecolor($out_w, $out_h);

$curr_x = 0;
while($curr_x < $out_w){
    imagecopy($out, $src, $curr_x, 0, 0, 0, $src_w, $src_h);
    $curr_x += $src_w;
}

imagejpeg($out, $outfile, 100);
imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($out);
```